# Preventing next tab if current tab have empty field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form having few questions set, each displayed at a time (like a slide). I want to prevent next set if current set has an empty field. Below is my script that navigates through each questions set. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $questions = $('#questions .question');
var currentQuestion = $('#questions .question.active').index();

$('#next').click(function() {
    $($questions[currentQuestion]).slideUp(function() {
        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion == $questions.length - 1) {
            $('#next').css('display', 'none');
            $('#submit').css('display', 'inline');
        }else{
            $('#next').css('display', 'inline');
            $('#submit').css('display', 'none');
        }
        $('#back').css('display', 'inline');
        $($questions[currentQuestion]).slideDown();
    });
}); 

$('#back').click(function() {
    $($questions[currentQuestion]).slideUp(function() {
        currentQuestion--;
        if (currentQuestion == 0) {
            $('#back').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $('#back').css('display', 'inline');
        }
        $('#next').css('display', 'inline');
        $('#submit').css('display', 'none');
        $($questions[currentQuestion]).slideDown();
    });
});
```

});

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moinchoudhari/cuqerfxr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across your question and decided to fork your fiddle.

You should make a function that checks your conditions before continuing on to the next tab.
In your case, the conditions would be: *All fields must be filled*

I've added this function that checks the active section and returns true / false, in order to continue.

```
function validateFormSection() {
    var valid = true; //As long as it's true, we may continue
    var section = $('.question.active'); //Find the active section
    var inputs = section.find('input'); //Get all its inputs
    inputs.each(function(index, el) {
        if ( $(el).val() == "" ) {
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MichielSteeg/yya8qoj3/)

On the third page, the form would submit whether all fields are empty or not.
You can prevent this by hooking onto the submit function and checking for empty fields.
If they're empty, we use `e.preventDefault();` to keep it from submitting.
If they're filled, we simply submit by doing `$('form').submit();`

```
$('form').submit( function (e) { //Hook into the submit event
    var valid = validateFormSection(); //Check if our fields are filled
    if ( valid ) { //They are filled?
        $('form').submit(); //Very well, let's submit!
    } else {
        e.preventDefault(); //If not, prevent the (default) submit behaviour
    }
});
```

The fiddle has been edited to reflect these changes.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MichielSteeg/yya8qoj3/)

Comment: More info in the chatroom I posted above

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if(!$('.question').eq(currentQuestion).find('input').filter(function(){return this.value==""}).length)` to check if there are empty fields. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/cuqerfxr/1/

- `$('.question')` selects all the questions
- `.eq(currentQuestion)` selects the question you're currently at
- `.find('input')` selects all the input fields inside the current question
- `.filter(function(){return this.value==""})` selects only empty input fields
- `.length` counts the amount of matches, e.g. amount of empty inputs
- `if(number)` returns `true` with a positive value, e.g. if there were any empty inputs
- `!` in front of it all inverts it, returning `true` if there are *no* empty fields

Comment: Thanks @Ilpo, however the script by Michiel is more preferable.